Is there a way to do easy SSR in React using something similar to onServerPrefetch hook in Vue3?
I'm currently using Vite / React / TS to build my own SSR framework without using NextJS or Remix in order to make everything as simple as possible.
I'm referring to this link: https://github.com/mengdu/vite-react-ssr and it helps me to give a vague concept of how components are pre-rendered on the server-side first.
SSR works well for static imported components, but not for something like <div>{dataFromAPI}</div> or lazy-loaded components. (React Router v6)
It seems like I should build my own protocol to implement data pre-fetching and rendering it on the server side, not like I do it in Vue just using onServerPrefetch hook.
Should I just use built-in SSR frameworks like NextJS or Remix?
